# How to remove duplicate records from multiple tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a situation like this:

I have 3 tables, for example:

- table phones
- table computers
- table printers

Every table has the same column named "Address" and every column has the same record "06-00-00-00-00-00" (a duplicate record).

Now, I was wondering if it's possible somehow to check all the records from all of the tables and delete the duplicate records from table "computers" and table "printers" but leave the record in table "phones"

In other words: Delete all the duplicate records from all of the tables except from one chosen table (in this case table "phones").

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Pls see the following guidance on asking a good sql related question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: do you want to delete in same query from both tables or different queries.

Comment: I would prefer to delete it in the same query ... because this query is going to be a part of a script that is checking for the duplicate records in all the tables and deletes all the duplicates except from one table (as I already explained).

Comment: You **cant** delete multiple tables in the same query, you need create a transaction and perform multiple delete queries.

Comment: Ok, so how should I do it, it can be multiple queries, it doesn't matter. The most important thing is that I find the duplicate records from all the tables and delete them except one.

Comment: could you provide [MCVE]

Comment: Hi @davejal, I've posted another question that is better explained. Take a look if you have time: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41738428/5961759

Answer (score 0):

For deleting records,

```
DELETE TABLE TABLE1
WHERE ADDRESS = (SELECT ADDRESS FROM TABLE2)
```