# Insert record to the table only if doesn't exist in other tables - MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I am doing some Bluetooth project where I have a device sniffing for MAC addresses. I want those sniffed addresses to be saved to a certain table (In my case called "Visitors").

[image]

Now, the thing is. The tables I_year_student and II_year_student will have a manually inserted records. I want all found devices to be saved to the Table "Visitors". The problem is: sometimes one MAC address which is already in the table I_year_student is going to be sniffed by the device again, and of course, it is going to be saved to the database again, more precisely, to the table "Visitors". Now I have two identical records in two different tables and I don't want that to happen.

Is there a way, where after my device finds a certain MAC address, to check if the record already exists in other tables. Something like this:

- I found a "new" MAC address
- Before inserting that record to the table "Visitors" check if there is a similar record in other tables in the database.
- If there is a similar record ignore it.
- If the record is unique save it to the table "Visitors"

A part of the code for sniffing and inputing to the table Visitors is written below:

```
if len(nearby_devices) > 0:
print(len(nearby_devices))

for addr, name in nearby_devices:
    try:

        cur.execute("""INSERT INTO Visitors
                           (Address, Name)
                       VALUES
                           (%s,%s)
                    """, (addr, name)
                   )
        con.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, thanks everyone for help but I think I found and answer and manage to solve the problem:

My situation was this. I have a device that is always sniffing for MAC addresses on Bluetooth protocol and I wanted to save all the addresses that I've found to MySQL database for later processing. Also, I wanted to save those addresses by separating them based on different profiles, for example:

- mac_address1 : Column: ProfileID (**typeA**)
- mac_address2 : Column: ProfileID (**typeB**)
- mac_address3 : Column: ProfileID (**typeC**), and so on...

The thing is that my database already has some manually added mac addresses and I didn't want my new addresses (that could also be old, because some devices can enter the sniffing area again) to be saved again under some ProfileID, while I already have them under some other ProfileID.

So, after some thinking I wrote the query and tested it and now it's working fine.

```
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO ordenador
                           (Address, Name, ProfileID)
                       VALUES
                           (%s,%s,'public')
                       ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                       ProfileID = VALUES(ProfileID)
                    """, (addr, name)
                   )
```

Now, when my device catches a "new" mac address, he inputs that record to the table "ordenador" and if the record for "new" mac address already exists there, it just update the record to the old one. In other case, if the record doesn't exist there, the query inputs the record under a ProfileID, in my case "public".

All the suggestions and thoughts are welcomed. I hope this will help to someone who already had some similar issues.